# Default Route for every http request

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I need to set a default function for my web app that return for every http request a maintenance view.

I did it:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/'], function() {
     return view('maintenance');
});
```

but when I go for example to http://www.mypage.com/profile
it works.

How should I set my routes?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not setup a middleware group and run an if statement?

Comment: @Roland, I think it's more to the point of if the page is having work done to it, it'll show its under maintenance rather than not found.

Comment: Can you paste me the code please? @Option

Comment: laravel has a maintenance mode feature https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#maintenance-mode

Comment: How are your pages stored firstly, via DB or just hardcoded in?

Comment: I want just a maintenance page for every http request

Comment: @Fran, is this to throw the entire website into maintenance mode or just some pages? Once you answer this i'll be able to assist further..

Answer (score 0):

To make this the easiest way possible to take the entire website into maintenance mode (as I am unsure if this is every page at once or separately).

You could do the following via using the database:

`php artisan make:migration create_maintenance_mode_table --create=maintenance_mode`

Within this file add a simple:

`$table->integer('enabled')->default(0);`

Then run `php artisan migrate`

Then setup the Model:

`php artisan make:model Maintenance`

within this file add:

```
protected $table = 'maintenance_mode';

protected $fillable = [ 'enabled' ];
```

After this we need to set up the middleware:

`php artisan make:middleware CheckMaintenanceMode`

Within this files handle function you need to add:

```
$maintenance = Maintenance::select('enabled')->get()->first();

        if ($maintenance->enabled == 1)
        {
            return view('maintenance');
        }

        return $next($request);
```

Within the kernel.php file add within `$routeMiddleware`

`'maintenance' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckMaintenanceMode::class,`

You now need to setup the views file: `maintenance.blade.php`

Now within the routes file you need to add the following around all of your other route requests:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['maintenance']], function () {
    // Other Routes
});
```

Seems fairly long winded and you can do it other ways but this is something I'd use on my own projects.

Answer (score 0):

why dont u use the integrated maintenance mode ?

```
php artisan down
```

to disable maintenance mode use

```
php artisan up
```

to exclude your IP to continue development you can try this middleware

```
class CheckForMaintenanceMode {
protected $app;

public function __construct(Application $app)
{
    $this->app = $app;
}

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $white = $_ENV['MAINTENANCE_WHITELIST'];        // Get WhiteListed IP from .ENV
    $ip = $request->ip();                           // Get Visior IP with no Proxy (like Cloudflare)
    // $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];         // Get Real Visitor IP with CloudFlare enabled
    if ($this->app->isDownForMaintenance() &&
        !in_array($ip, [$white]))               
    {
      $maintenanceMode = new MaintenanceMode($this->app);
      return $maintenanceMode->handle($request, $next);
    }
    return $next($request);
}}
```

dont forget to add the middleware to /app/http/kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
   ...
   \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
   ...
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has maintenance mode support without

1. Execute **php artisan down** in the command line for enable maintenance mode (you can use php artisan up, for disable maintenance)
2. If you dont want use artisan. You can create 'down' file manually in storage/framework/down for enable maintenance or remove it for disable

Also, you can create **maintenance view** in resources/views/errors/503.blade.php

MORE INFO: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#maintenance-mode